# Como saber a rota antes de redirecionar no Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código que redireciona para uma página 404 caso o path não esteja definido dentro da aplicação.

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'paginas/pagina404' }
```

Mas gostaria de mostrar na página 404 o caminho que tentaram acessar, tem alguma forma de fazer isso?
Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro criar um evento para escutar a alteração de rotas em seu componente principal relativo ao `<router-outlet>` e publicar as modificações em um serviço capturando-as na sua página de 404. Exemplo de como escutar:

```js
urlAtual: string = '';
urlAnterior: string = '';

ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events.subscribe((e: any) => {
    if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      this.urlAnterior = this.urlAtual;
      this.urlAtual = e.url;
    }
  });
}
```

Após capturar as modificações você publica em seu serviço/gerenciamento de estado.